# bat. добавление значение к введенному выражению

Tags: windows, shell, bat

Нужно написать программу в .bat, которая бы к введенному IP адресу добавляла значение Например ввели 192.168.1.1, а переменой бы присвоилась бы 192.168.1.2 Каким образом можно это реализовать? Перекопал интернет но ничего толкового не нашел. Код должен работать исключительно на windows 7-10. Приведенный код не помогает:

```
set /p ipadres="Вводим IP адрес:"
set /a ip =%ipadres%+1
echo %ip%
```

Comment: SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p adres="Вводим IP адрес:"
for /f "delims=. tokens=1-4" %%a in ("%adres%") do (

  set /a last=%%d + 1
  set  shlus=%%a.%%b.%%c.!last!
  echo %shlus%
  set /a last1=%%d + 2
  set  ip=%%a.%%b.%%c.!last1!
  echo %ip%
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно разбить введенный адрес на отдельные токены, модифицировать последнее число и склеить обратно

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p ipadres="Вводим IP адрес:"
for /f "delims=. tokens=1-4" %%a in ("%ipadres%") do (
  set /a last=%%d + 1
  set ip=%%a.%%b.%%c.!last!
)
echo %ip%
```

И вывод

```
>test.bat
>SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>set /p ipadres="Вводим IP адрес:"
Вводим IP адрес:192.168.1.1
>for /F "delims=. tokens=1-4" %a in ("192.168.1.1") do (
set /a last=%d + 1
 set ip=%a.%b.%c.!last!
)

>(
set /a last=1 + 1
 set ip=192.168.1.!last!
)

>echo 192.168.1.2
192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Нет. Увы. не Работает (((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: @ИванИванов Обманываете. Работает все

Comment: Ошибка. Коменты убирал, и переделывал - не помогает Вот Ошибка на уровне скопировал - встави (с убиранием коментов). for /F "delims=. tokens=1-4" a in ("192.168.1.1") do (

Comment: @ИванИванов у меня в коде нет никаких комментов. Скопируйте мой код как есть в отдельный файл и запустите

Comment: Вот поверишь нет. Но копировал, вставлял и запускал. Даже файл назвал test.bat. Пишет то ошибка синтаксиса. Есть ICQ или ВК?

Comment: @ИванИванов Не поверю. Вот чат - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49596/bat-- давайте сюда